# Scaling Text File IO Application

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java application that reads in a comma separated text file, peforms some calculations on the data and writes the updated data to a new file. The input file contains a about 500 million rows, so I'm trying to scale the below as much as possible so that I don't get an out of memory exception when I run it.  Any ideas on how to improve the below?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class CsvTest {

  public void readFile() {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;

    try {

      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\input.txt"));
      FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\output.txt");
      out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

      String line = null;

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        out.write(line + "\r\n");
      }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
      try {
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
        if(out != null){
            out.close();
        }
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
          System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CsvTest test = new CsvTest();
    test.readFile();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an out of memory error or just worried about it? It looks amenable to map/reduce if it's quite slow. What specific problem are you seeing?

Comment: I'm concerned about it, haven't run the huge file yet...

Comment: It took all of 3 seconds for my app to process a 137MB file which has 2 million rows in it using your readFile() method...I think your code looks fine except for the need to separate duties (you should specific methods for reading and writing)

Comment: It looks like my input file will be 500 million rows.  Will the code above read it all into memory at once and processes line by line?  I can split the input file up into multiple files if that will help?

Comment: 500 million rows will be a big, big file...why not load that into a database of some sort and write your application against the database?  It will be much easier and efficient to work with that many rows of data in a database.  Otherwise, you'll definitely want to chunk out those rows into separate files and possibly run the app in a multi-threaded fashion

Comment: this is a one time thing, so I'm trying to get away with the quickest solution.

Comment: I was able to process a 35 GB file with 500 million rows in it in 23 minutes in my Eclipse IDE using your readFile() method.  Probably not the most efficient way using BufferedReader/Writer but if it's just for a one time thing, I think you're safe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty good, I mean you are streaming data from the input into the output holding only one line in memory, so it's basically O(1) in terms of the memory requirements, you can't get better than that I think.

Buffers in the buffered reader and the buffered writer are constant with negligible, relative to the size of multi-gb files, memory usage.

EDIT: And garbage collector should work fine collecting the unused data, at least my experience with it in the similar cases of data processing was pretty positive.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using [java.nio.channels.FileChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html).  There are also comparisons of the standard java.io and java.nio, like [this](http://geekomatic.ch/2008/09/06/1220730740479.html) for example.  NIO seems to be the way to go for massive I/O operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
    out.write(line + "\r\n");
```

could go as

```
    out.write(line);
    out.write("\r\n");
```

If you process cells, with same object values, like Strings, it would be good to not hold the same value as more than one object instance.

```
private Map<Object, Object> sharedMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

public Object uniqueObject(Object value) {
    Object sharedValue = sharedMap.get(value);
    if (sharedValue == null) {
        sharedValue = value;
        sharedMap.put(sharedValue, sharedValue);
    }
    return sharedValue;
}
```